# How to search for nearby towns using Google Maps API?

Tags: google-maps, search

I have a KML file with the coordinates of about 300 towns. I'd want to use Google Maps API to search for 5-10 nearby towns respect to the user position, but I don't read anything useful in Maps documentation. May you help me?

Comment: It will be a mobile webapp.

Comment: Are the "towns" polygons?  Or just points?